# How to restart my network properly after binding two ips with single nic in debian?

Tags: shell, networking, debian

I have binded two ips  with single nic (Network Interface Card) in debian this way.

step 1:

vim /etc/network/interfaces into the following format:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
auto eth0:1
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Now 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.100 are all binded with my local nic.

step2:
vim /etc/network/ifstate into the following format:

```
lo=lo
eth0=eth0
eth0:1=eth0:1
```

It is time to restart my network now.

```
 /etc/init.d/networking restart
[....] Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not r[warnble some interfaces ... (warning).
[....] Reconfiguring network interfaces...RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
Ignoring unknown interface eth0:1=eth0:1.
done.

ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

The two ip have been binded with single NIC when to reboot my pc.
I want to know the proper way to restart networking not to reboot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically to `stop/start/restart` the network interface on [Debian](https://www.debian.org/):

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop
/etc/init.d/networking start
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

To verify changes after making changes and restarting:

```
ifconfig -a
```

https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding